# Set function in C++ doesn't work

Tags: c++

I am totally newbie here, so please be forgiving.
As I don't get the result  I want I'll post here the whole code.

```
class DigitalPet
{
public:
    DigitalPet (std::string );
    ~DigitalPet ();
    void talk ();
    void play ();
    void feed ();
    void setMemberName ( std::string );
    void setMemberMood ();
    std::string getMemberMood () const;
    int getMemberHunger () const;
    int getMemberBoredom () const;


private:
    std::string m_memberName;
    int m_memberHunger;
    int m_memberBoredom;
    std::string m_memberMood;
};
```

Implementation.

```
DigitalPet::DigitalPet(std::string name)
{
    setMemberName (name);
    m_memberHunger = 8;
    m_memberBoredom = 4;
    setMemberMood();
}
DigitalPet::~DigitalPet()
{

};
void DigitalPet::talk()
{
    std::cout << "\nHello. My name is " << m_memberName << " and I am " << getMemberMood()<< std::endl;
    m_memberHunger -= 2;
    m_memberBoredom -= 2;
}
void DigitalPet::play()
{
    m_memberHunger -= 4;
    m_memberBoredom -= 2;
}
void DigitalPet::feed()
{
    m_memberHunger += 4;
    m_memberBoredom -= 1;
}
void DigitalPet::setMemberName ( std::string name)
{
    while (name.length() > 10 )
    {
        std::cout << "The name you entered is too long. Please enter a smaller name!!!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

    }
    m_memberName = name;
}
void DigitalPet::setMemberMood()
{

    if (m_memberHunger <= 0 && m_memberBoredom <= 0 )
   {
       m_memberMood = "mad";
    }
   else if (m_memberHunger > 0 && m_memberHunger <= 4 && m_memberBoredom > 0 && m_memberBoredom <= 2)
   {
       m_memberMood = "frustrated";
  }
    else if (m_memberHunger > 4 && m_memberHunger <= 8 && m_memberBoredom > 2 && m_memberBoredom <= 4)
    {
        m_memberMood = "good";
    }
    else if (m_memberHunger > 8 && m_memberHunger <= 12 && m_memberBoredom > 4 && m_memberBoredom <= 6)
{
        m_memberMood = "happy";
}
}
std::string DigitalPet::getMemberMood() const
{
    return m_memberMood;
}
int DigitalPet::getMemberHunger() const
{
    return m_memberHunger;
}
int DigitalPet::getMemberBoredom() const
{
    return m_memberBoredom;
}
```

And where I call them.

```
int main()
{
    DigitalPet Yama("Yama");

    Yama.talk();

    std::cout << Yama.getMemberBoredom()<< std::endl;

    std::cout << Yama.getMemberHunger() << std::endl;

    Yama.talk();

    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that though m_memberHunger and m_memberBoredom decrease it continues to type mood "good".

Comment: Please post your program, we don't like guessing what you *might* have done. I cannot see any `main()`.

Comment: where is called setMemberMood()?

Comment: I have a hunch you're setting and getting on different instances. We need to see your calling code.

Comment: Also, you probably want ` << std::endl` after ` << getMemberMood()` in DigitalPet::talk

Comment: Don't use `cin` in setter methods. Pass a `std::string` parameter instead and do `cin` and validation outside, or have a specialized `istream& operator<<(istream, MyClass&)` override to validate the inputs.

Comment: I have posted main (). I again problem is with the setMemberMood function.

Comment: You should pass strings by constant reference if you are not going to modify the parameters.

Comment: Prefer to initialize variables in constructors directly (without calling methods).  Also use *initialization lists*.

Comment: The `talk` method doesn't modify member variables, so it should be declared as a constant method.

Answer (score 7):

This is the time to learn how to use a debugger.

Your `setMemberName` method will never set the name if it's the correct length from the start. Only errors will trigger the actual setting of the member variable.

Comment: The problem is not with setMemberName function, it is with setMemberMood.

Comment: @Stepan How do you know  that the problem is with `setMemberMood`, when you aren't calling it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the function itself, here it is modified:

```
void DigitalPet::setMemberName ( std::string name)
{
    while (name.length() > 10 )
    {
        std::cout << "The name you entered is too long. Please enter a smaller name!!!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;
    }

    m_memberName = name;
}
```

The problem was you only assign a name when the parameter was longer than 10 characters and you didn't check it again, just assigned it.

Comment: The problem is not with setMemberName function, it is with setMemberMood.